# help 32 by 64 rgb matrix pong game

Tags: pi-pico, matrix-creator

Hi there i want to make a pong game i can currently get a image to display or images scrolling if anyone out there that knows how to do this or can help any info is much aprecitated

```py
import time
from math import sin
import board
import displayio
import rgbmatrix
import framebufferio
import adafruit_imageload
import terminalio
from adafruit_display_text.label import Label

displayio.release_displays()
matrix = rgbmatrix.RGBMatrix(
    width=64, bit_depth=1,
    rgb_pins=[board.GP0, board.GP1, board.GP2, board.GP3, board.GP4, board.GP5],
    addr_pins=[board.GP6, board.GP7, board.GP8, board.GP9],
    clock_pin=board.GP10, latch_pin=board.GP12, output_enable_pin=board.GP13)
   
display = framebufferio.FramebufferDisplay(matrix, auto_refresh=False)

g = displayio.Group()
b, p = adafruit_imageload.load("pi-logo32b.bmp")
t = displayio.TileGrid(b, pixel_shader=p)
t.x = 20
g.append(t)

l = Label(text="", font=terminalio.FONT, color=0xffffff, line_spacing=.7)
g.append(l)

display.show(g)

target_fps = 50
ft = 1/target_fps
now = t0 = time.monotonic_ns()
deadline = t0 + ft

p = 1
q = 17
while True:
    tm = (now - t0) * 1e-9
    x = l.x - 1
    if x < -40:
        x = 63
    y =  round(12 + sin(tm / p) * 6)
    l.x = x
    l.y = y
    display.refresh(target_frames_per_second=target_fps, minimum_frames_per_second=0)
    while True:
        now = time.monotonic_ns()
        if now > deadline:
            break
        time.sleep((deadline - now) * 1e-9)
    deadline += ft# Write your code here :-)
```

---

or multiple images showing scrolling 3 at a time

```py
import random
import time

import board
import displayio
import framebufferio
import rgbmatrix

displayio.release_displays()

matrix = rgbmatrix.RGBMatrix(
    width=64, height=32, bit_depth=3,
    rgb_pins=[board.GP0, board.GP1, board.GP2, board.GP3, board.GP4, board.GP5],
    addr_pins=[board.GP6, board.GP7, board.GP8, board.GP9],
    clock_pin=board.GP10, latch_pin=board.GP12, output_enable_pin=board.GP13)
display = framebufferio.FramebufferDisplay(matrix, auto_refresh=False)



filename = "emoji.bmp"

# CircuitPython 6 & 7 compatible
bitmap_file = open(filename, 'rb')
bitmap = displayio.OnDiskBitmap(bitmap_file)
pixel_shader = getattr(bitmap, 'pixel_shader', displayio.ColorConverter())


STOPPED, RUNNING, BRAKING = range(3)

# Return a duplicate of the input list in a random (shuffled) order.
def shuffled(seq):
    return sorted(seq, key=lambda _: random.random())


class Wheel(displayio.TileGrid):
    def __init__(self):
        # Portions of up to 3 tiles are visible.
        super().__init__(bitmap=bitmap, pixel_shader=pixel_shader,
                         width=1, height=3, tile_width=20, tile_height=24)
        self.order = shuffled(range(20))
        self.state = STOPPED
        self.pos = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.x = 0
        self.stop_time = time.monotonic_ns()

    def step(self):
        # Update each wheel for one time step
        if self.state == RUNNING:
            # Slowly lose speed when running, but go at least speed 64
            self.vel = max(self.vel * 9 // 10, 64)
            if time.monotonic_ns() > self.stop_time:
                self.state = BRAKING
        elif self.state == BRAKING:
            # More quickly lose speed when braking, down to speed 7
            self.vel = max(self.vel * 85 // 100, 7)

      
        self.pos = (self.pos + self.vel) % 7680

        # Compute the rounded Y coordinate
        yy = round(self.pos / 16)
        # Compute the offset of the tile (tiles are 24 pixels tall)
        yyy = yy % 24
        # Find out which tile is the top tile
        off = yy // 24

       
        if self.state == BRAKING and self.vel == 7 and yyy < 4:
            self.pos = off * 24 * 16
            self.vel = 0
            self.state = STOPPED

        
        self.y = yyy - 20
        for i in range(3):
            self[i] = self.order[(19 - i + off) % 20]


    def kick(self, i):
        self.state = RUNNING
        self.vel = random.randint(256, 320)
        self.stop_time = time.monotonic_ns() + 3_000_000_000 + i * 350_000_000


g = displayio.Group()
wheels = []
for idx in range(3):
    wheel = Wheel()
    wheel.x = idx * 22
    wheel.y = -20
    g.append(wheel)
    wheels.append(wheel)
display.show(g)

orders = [shuffled(range(20)), shuffled(range(20)), shuffled(range(20))]


for si, oi in zip(wheels, orders):
    for idx in range(3):
        si[idx] = oi[idx]


def all_stopped():
    return all(si.state == STOPPED for si in wheels)

for idx, si in enumerate(wheels):
    si.kick(idx)

while True:
        display.refresh(minimum_frames_per_second=0)
    if all_stopped():
        
        for idx in range(100):
            display.refresh(minimum_frames_per_second=0)
        for idx, si in enumerate(wheels):
            si.kick(idx)

    for idx, si in enumerate(wheels):
        si.step()
```

i can provided wiring diagram if any one wants to use this code

Comment: There are a plenty of articles out there on how to write a pong game in Python, I suggest you have a look at one of those for the basic game logic parts.
You will also have to implement input to move the paddles, think the best way would be to have two potentiometers to control them, one for each player.